# Is using sprinkler system in orchard a wise choice?

Tags: fruit-trees, irrigation, sprinkler-system, drip-system, cover-crop

My orchard has walnut, apricot and apple trees and I have alfalfa as cover crop. For now I am using surface irrigation. I am planing to change my system to drip irrigation or sprinkler irrigation.

[image: Orchard]

- Drip irrigation: Good option But I would lose my cover crop (which makes my orchard beautiful)
- Sprinkler: My cover crop will survive. Also I can use this system to overcome late frost in spring. But some people tell me sprinkling water on tree trunk and branches is detrimental for tree. and Some say It would kill your tree.

What should I do?